# How does MySQL's SELECT WHERE do integer comparisons?

Tags: mysql, select, comparison

Let's say I have a MySQL query such as

```
SELECT `id` FROM `posts` WHERE `views` >= 100
```

How would this be done by MySQL? Does it select every single value from the database, check if the views count is greater than 100, and add that to the results if it is?

If this was a query on a HashMap in Java, it would look something like this

```
Map<String, Integer> views = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

for(String id : views.keys()){
    if(views.get(id) >= 100){
        results.add(id);
    }
}

return results;
```

But that doesn't seem very efficient if the table had tens or hundreds of thousands of rows. How does `SELECT WHERE` do integer comparison? And if it gets every single value from the database and checks it against the `WHERE` conditions, is it resource-intensive, and should it be used in a production environment?

Comment: It is slow. It is super slow. If it isn't, it's because 1. there are few rows, or 2. there are indexes on the column (buffer/caching the ranges)

Comment: If the `views` is indexed, then it looks up in the b-tree structure where the 100 is and it contains the information about all the rows positions that contain the value larger than 100. If it isn't indexed, then it goes through all the rows, one by one and adds the found result to the buffer with found rows. If `views` is indexed, but if it's a poor candidate (meaning that index can't help reduce number of lookups), it goes through all the records. Hundreds of millions of rows is not a huge issue if you have fast I/O subsystem that can get data to the CPU in a fast manner.

Comment: As the above comments say, the most efficient way to get the results of that query is to use an index on the `views` column. See here for how mySQLuses indexes: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html
How Java* might do a similar thing is neither here nor there, unless you're  planning to write your own DB engine in Java. * Note that I know nothing about Java!

Comment: It also depends on how many rows actually have views>100. In some cases full scan will be faster than index scan. Database engines have quite sophisticated optimizers that will look for the best way to run your query and it will be most probably much faster than whaever you can think up in Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given a table with no indexes, scanning and testing each row is exactly what MySQL does. This is why indexes are critical for performance.

With an index MySQL will look through it and find the spot where `100` sits, and then reads rows from that point on. This works for bounds like `<`, `>` or the `BETWEEN` operator.

An un-indexed table should be considered a random list of data, there's no inherent order. An indexed table is sorted by one or more columns, so retrieval is easy. Consider finding all people with the last name "Thompson" in the phone book versus a box full of names written on scraps of paper. In one case you can just flip to the right page and read from there, in the other you must read every single name in the box.

If you want to know how MySQL will handle your query, do this:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT id FROM posts WHERE views >= 100
```

If you see "table scan" that means it must test every row and an index should be added.

Answer (score 2):

Well when you have no index on column `views` that means that engine have to scan all datapages and do a comparison for each row. If this is true then it indeed is like you had described.

Now when there is an index then there is searching in B-tree with logarithmic time. Engine can easily determine all required datapages as index is ordered and load only those datapages. Now there are nuances like if you are selecting the same column then engine doesn't need to do more reads or if you are selecting some other columns it has to do clustered index lookup for each row. Etc. Etc.